# Full text search - Not stopping StopWords

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I created a full text index using the SQL Server Full Text wizard but when I pass in a search term it doesn't ignore stopwords.

i.e. This returns rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.T_Restaurant AS Restaurant
JOIN dbo.SearchView AS SearchView ON SearchView.id = Restaurant.id
WHERE CONTAINS(SearchView.TotalSearchField, ' indian & bridgwater ')
```

But this doesn't:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.T_Restaurant AS Restaurant
JOIN dbo.SearchView AS SearchView ON SearchView.id = Restaurant.id
WHERE CONTAINS(SearchView.TotalSearchField, ' indian & in & bridgwater ')
```

I know that 'in' is a stopword in the English language and yet it doesn't appear to be ignored.  The index is using the System stopword list according to its properties.  Have I missed a step to set the stopword list up?

Many thanks,

Chris.

Answer (score 1):

Does this FTS syntax work better? I think it will have taken indian & bridgewater to be a phrase rather than looking for the words which is what I think you are trying to do.

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.T_Restaurant AS Restaurant
JOIN dbo.SearchView AS SearchView ON SearchView.id = Restaurant.id
WHERE CONTAINS(SearchView.TotalSearchField, '"indian" AND "bridgwater"')

SELECT *
FROM dbo.T_Restaurant AS Restaurant
JOIN dbo.SearchView AS SearchView ON SearchView.id = Restaurant.id
WHERE CONTAINS(SearchView.TotalSearchField, '"indian" AND "IN" AND "bridgwater"')
```

Comment: :(  Sadly that doesn't work either. Thanks for your input though, much appreciated.

Comment: I can't get into sql server till the morning; what does this return

select * from sys.dm_fts_parser (‘ “indian & in & bridgewater”  ‘, 1033, 77,0)

It should show the noisewords that are going in your language - assuming 1033 is your codepage. You can check that with

select [name], alias, lcid from master.sys.syslanguages;

Comment: Thanks for your help so far buddy, I really appreciate your time.  I have run the query you suggested (with an edit for the StopListID linked to my index) and this is what I get (removed a few odd columns):

1 Exact Match indian
2 Noise Word in
3 Exact Match bridgwater

Crazy, it's obviously being recognised as a noise word and yet when I query the DB with the noise word it returns no rows. Grrr!

Comment: Last resort is to check the index direct using the dmv's. I don;t recall the syntax but check http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280607.aspx you can check row by row to see whats in the index.

Comment: I can see all of the indexed words and none of the stopwords are in the list (presumably because the population process strips them out).  I'll do some more digging online tomorrow, as I probably won't have time today.  Many thanks again, your input has been very valued.  This kind of knotty problem is very difficult to get to the bottom of and it's good to get someone else's input.